# Are there any executable compressors that work with 64 bit binaries?

Tags: windows, compression

I'm looking for a tool like [Bitsum Technologies' excellent PECompact](http://www.bitsum.com/) tool for compressing Windows executables, but which works with 64 bit binaries. Does such a tool exist?

Note: I don't care about the supposed obfuscation such a compressor provides; I'd simply like to reduce the size of my binaries.

Comment: Why?
compression defeats the file mapping mechanisms that allow the exe's to be directly paged - hence increase the swapfile usage and generally act as an anchor to system performace.

Comment: @Chris Becke: Because many of my users are on Dial-Up connections, and PECompact drops the executable size from 1.2MB to 0.3MB for my 32 bit builds.

Comment: Zip files and self extracting installers have been used since before - well - almost everyone else switched from dialup to broadband.

Comment: @Chris Becke: Yes, but that doesn't work as nice as PECompact. This app runs for less than a second -- performance is not a requirement whatsoever. I don't care how it performs in that respect, I just want the user to be able to download a smaller binary. Single binary xcopy deployment is important for this application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes; I believe that [MPRESS](http://www.matcode.com/mpress.htm) will do the job just fine. And it works with .NET executables to boot!

Comment: Does it operate by extracting the executable to a temporary directory or is the entire process in-memory as it is with UPX or PECompact?

Comment: It is in-place like UPX -- at least, as far as I can see. I compressed my local notepad.exe and ran it, went to task manager > processes > right-click on notepad.exe, properties, and it showed up as the original compressed executable, not a temporary file or stub.